# Receiving Request Header Error - AJAX/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, header, request

I've got a simple script trying to access publicly available data provided by the USGS as a JSON endpoint. Right now the script is returning HTTP status code 0: 'undefined' which I understand to be a blanket status code that can mean a lot of things. The pared down code I've been trying to test is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#query').click(function() {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=08170500&parameterCd=00060',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');            
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language' , 'en-US,en;q=0.5');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection' , 'keep-alive');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Host' , 'waterservices.usgs.gov');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' , '1');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36');
        }
    })
    .done(function () {
        alert( "success");
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("failure");
        $('#sitedesc').text(jqXHR.status + ' - ' + jqXHR.responseText);
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert("complete");
    });
});
</script>
```

I've narrow down that the beforeSend function appears to be causing the problem, which made me think it's a CORS issue. But the documentation from the USGS water services explicitly states that the service supports CORS (https://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/IV-Service.html#CORS).

Removing the request headers isn't an option either, as this returns a 403 forbidden status code, which is the reason why USGS staff suggested that I needed to provide the headers in the first place.

Anyone have any insight? Thanks!

Disclaimer: I'm not a software engineer nor is JavaScript my forte :)

Comment: I removed the `beforeSend` handler and it works fine.  If you can open the Url in your browser (which you can) then you know a regular GET method works fine, without any particular headers.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Here on my work machine, if I remove the beforeSend handler, I get a 403 forbidden error. To test, I uploaded the script to an external web server and it worked. Must be something with my work network. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Have you tried just opening the Url, without using the script?  Like I said, since it's a GET request it has exactly the same effect as using the script, but can often help give you some idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, running it directly from the url was successful from the getgo, so I was able to gather that it had something to do with the JS executing the request in the browser. I get the 403 error when executing the script in Chrome/Edge/Firefox, but it works in IE.  Appears to be some sort of network security setting or protocol on our work network, and I've got our network team is looking into it.